# Laravel: how to format $table->links(); from $table = Table::paginate(int)

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-4

./app/views/index.blade.php

```
{{ $users->links();}}
```

Displays this
«
1
2
»

How do I change it so it's all on one line?

in the model file I use the paginate function from Laravel

./app/model/User.php

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::paginate(5);
    return View::make('users.index', compact('users'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new view and set it in `app/config/views.php`:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Pagination View
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This view will be used to render the pagination link output, and can
| be easily customized here to show any view you like. A clean view
| compatible with Twitter's Bootstrap is given to you by default.
|
*/

'pagination' => 'pagination::slider-3',
```

You can use some others Laravel provides:

```
'pagination' => 'pagination::slider',
'pagination' => 'pagination::simple',
```

Or you can change it to your own view:

```
'pagination' => 'layouts.partials.pagination',
```

The original ones are in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/Views/`

Comment: The line you showed was already in my views.php but thanks to your help I learned where there were 2 more premade views 'simple' and 'slider' which both work much better. And I know where to make my own views now. Thanks!  
  
app/config/views.php  
    
    'pagination' => 'pagination::simple'  
  
or   

    'pagination' => 'pagination::slider'

Comment: Sorry I didn't made me understand, but cool you got it! Edited to better explain. Cheers.